# I don't find the templates list when i open Xcode

Tags: xcode4.2

i have upgraded Xcode to the 4.2 version, and i have noticed that the list of templates(view based application, windows based application, etc) is missing, where can i find it? thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**In Xcode 4.2 you have to use Single-View Application Template.** 
It's the same as Navigation-based Application template.